# Very slow performance while Accessing data from mysql remote db hosted on godaddy directly using wpf desktop application with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework, linq

Basically I placed my DB on godaddy server and access data using wpf by connecting to db directly. It did the task but it took so much time whenever I perform any operation on database using entity framework linq queries . It took about 8-10 seconds to perform simple read operation .

I also tried hostgator server, cached views locally but same results .

I would like to know where I am getting wrong , is this a problem with wpf or server configurations ?

I tried to query database using workbench and it took about 5 seconds to fetch data and EXPLAIN statement returned following result:

http://prnt.sc/bx0yag

thanks

Comment: How long does it take to get the query result using MySQL Workbench?

Comment: @SirRufo 4.969 sec to fetch data from the table having only 821 rows

Comment: now use the same statement but add EXPLAIN before. Add the results to your question

Comment: @SirRufo Updated as suggested sir .

Comment: Well I can only see 0.496 seconds for the query. Then it will take 4.5 seconds to get the data from the server. And that is not caused by the database itself. Something on the network is very slow between provider and your location

Comment: is it something related to server processor speed ?

Comment: No - it is all about network

Comment: so shall I need to use internet with good speed ?

Comment: You know you are using a slow connection and you are really asking about slow performance? How do you think the data is transferred to you? Some magic spells? Sorry, but this is like asking why you cannot travel 100km in an hour with a car thats vmax is 25km/h

Comment: I tried with the connection having about 5-6 Mbps speed . Isn't it enough ? Sorry if I am asking a stupid question please .

Comment: Use math: 5Mbps = 5/8 MByte/second = 0.625 MB/second. Is the total amount of data around 2.8 MByte? Then you should expect that 4.5 seconds for transportation. If not, then check your connection if you really have that speed. Otherwise anything else between you and the server throttles the speed. If then you have not really an option to change that - choose a different hoster without that kind of throttle between

Comment: Where are other professionals who can help me may be. ?